# Domain name not working in AWS

Tags: domain-name-system, nginx, amazon-web-services, ruby-on-rails, phusion-passenger

I had previously hosted my domain in a different instance but for some reason I had to delete that instance and create a new one. I am now trying to host my domain in the new instance. So I went to my registrar`s account and deleted all the nameservers from the domain name and added the new nameserver. Then I added my domain into the hosted zone in aws.
[image]

After waiting for 2 3 hrs my domain is still now working but if I visit the public IP it works.

I have edited the /etc/hosts file and added domainname.com there and also I have edited the /sites-available/default and added

```
    server {
#        passenger_ruby /usr/bin/passenger_free_ruby;
        rails_env development; # add this if you get error like “Incomplete response received from application” from nginx / passenger
        listen 80 default_server;
        server_name fuitter.com, *.fuitter.com;
        root /usr/share/nginx/html/maggie/public/;

        # You must explicitly set 'passenger_enabled on', otherwise
        # Passenger won't serve this app.
        passenger_enabled on;
    }
```

I have restarted my nginx server but still it is not working.

Comment: I'm unclear what the problem is. Fuitter.com points to an IP (52.88.43.104). Is that the wrong IP? When I `nmap` it, it shows no open ports. Perhaps a security group (Amazon's firewalls) problem?

Comment: @Halfgaar no, the IP is correct, but when I browse fuitter.com or www.fuitter.com then it does not show my app page.

Comment: @Halfgaar, if it is a case of security group then, in inbound rule I have set HTTP to anywhere and SSh to custom ip and in outbound i have set all traffic to anywhere. Is there anything wrong with this?

Comment: Port 80 wasn't open before, but it is now. When I open it with a web browser, I see a page.

Comment: @Halfgaar, somehow it is not working for me.